# Explicitly Setting Regular Expression to Variable advantages

Tags: java, regex

So if I am going through a scanner object, why is it that the second block of code is considered more efficient? Is it because it is immutable in the second case?

```
while (scanner.hasNext( "-1*" ))
```

Versus

```
static final Pattern regexExample = Pattern.compile( "-1*" );  
while (scanner.hasNext( regexExample ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efficiency depends on how you use the regex. Regular expressions are compiled into a format that's actually used for the comparisons. The function that takes the regex as a `String` has to compile it on every call. The function that takes the precompiled `Pattern` just uses it directly. If you only ever call the regex once, it doesn't make much difference. If you call it repeatedly, the `Pattern` version saves the compilation step, so in that sense it's more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The second block is more efficient as it creates the regular expression object once and then reuses the compiled expression on each pass through the while loop. The first example creates a new regular expression object on each pass through the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the regex and passing it to the `hasNext(Pattern pattern)` method is not really more efficient as the `hasNext(String pattern)` of Scanner puts in cache the compiled `Pattern` created with the String.

Comment: The only issue I see with this - as trivial as it might be - is with the specification for `Scanner`. Reading the documentation doesn't say anything about caching the `Pattern`. Therefore this breaks encapsulation. If `Pattern`'s implementation were to change, this behavior could change completely and no longer be true.

Comment: @Obicere Relevant about the javadoc that doesn't refer it and chances of changing. The Scanner class uses massively the cache but it is true that it is not referenced.

Comment: Personally I prefer the first one as it is as much efficient (for now) and but it is much more readable.

Comment: And to follow up on this, the `Scanner` cache is only good for 7 items. If you match 8 patterns in the same order `1, 2, ...,7, 8, 1, 2, ...` it would always have a cache miss. Although this is super corner-case, theoretically its possible to break it with the current implementation.

Comment: 8 distinct patterns used and embedded in a even task ?  It 's indeed very very very theoretical :) I think that the design should be reviewed in this case :)

Comment: You are funny. I like that :)

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, Scanner `hasNext(Pattern pattern)` is more efficient than `hasNext(String arg0)`.
Internally Scanner class `hasNext(String arg0)` converting your string to a pattern and put it in cache then calling `hasNext(Pattern pattern)`.

See Scanner.hasNext(String arg0) definition:

```
 public boolean hasNext(String arg0) {
  return this.hasNext((Pattern)this.patternCache.forName(arg0));
}
```